# Equations and inequalities with compelx numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to solve a few equations and inequalities for my homework. I did most of them, but there are three I have problem with. Can someone give me a hint for each of them?

1. $|\frac{z+i}{z^2+i}|>1$

I tried to switch it to an algebraic form and then solve but I ended up with: $a^2+b^2+2b > a^4 +2a^2b^2 + b^4 + 4ab$  Which still gives me nothing.

2. $z^3=-\overline{z}$

I came up with 
$(|z|(\cos\alpha + i\sin \alpha))^3=-|z|(\cos-\alpha + i\sin -\alpha)$

$(|z|(\cos2\alpha + i\sin 2\alpha))^2 = -1$

$|z|(\cos2\alpha + i\sin 2\alpha) = \left\lbrace -i,i \right\rbrace$

And can't move on. But it's probably wrong way of thinking anyway.

3. $arg(-\overline{z}) \ge \pi$

I got $arg(z) \le 0$ so what? The only answer will be $\Im z=0\land \Re z>0$?

What should I do with $arg(z)=500\pi$? Transfrom it to $Arg(z)=0$ and then solve?

Comment: Do you have to find all z that satify these equations.

Comment: In 1 and 3 I have to draw on graph all z that satify equations/inequalities. In 2 I only need to find all of them.